# Is there any other term for the 'sharp nose' to avoid ambiguity?

Tags: word-request

The word *sharp* is just beyond its usual meaning and we all know that. In fact, when it comes to the human organs, sharp certainly means that they are more efficient in performing their duties!

> Don't hide there. She'll catch you in a jiffy. She has very sharp eyes 
>  StoneyB (Sir, I admire you!) has very sharp brain. He answers any question about the language English just like that.

But...

> *I'm afraid, no matter how hard we try to remove the smoke of cigarette from this room, my girlfriend will catch us. She has very **sharp** nose.* 
>   *"Ah, never mind. I love people with sharp nose. [They are sexy](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=1006050711799)!* BANG!!!

Sharp nose certainly means having [a keen sense of smell](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sharp-nosed) but it, unlike eyes and brain, is also referred to the shape, the body part's sharpness - a pointed nose here?

Comment: I recommend using [*sharp mind* instead of *sharp brain*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sharp+brain%2C+sharp+mind&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csharp%20brain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csharp%20mind%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

It is unusual to use sharp nose to refer to a pointed facial feature.

Much more common is to refer to the nose as *aquiline*.  Which means shaped like an eagle's beak.

Answer (score 1):

Only slightly (but hilariously) ambiguous, would be "**she has a nose like a bloodhound**".

Alternatively, you could just say "**she has a nose for these things**"

Or possibly "she has a very **acute** / **sensitive** nose"

Or even "she has a **remarkable** / **trained** nose"

Answer (score 1):

It is common to say that

Someone ***has a sharp sense of smell***.